# Inject environment and system variables from gradle to Intellij run and debug mode

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have some environment variables defined in my build.gradle that I'd like IntelliJ to automatically load when I run/debug unit tests or other kinds of tests (including with coverage and individual test runs)

Example:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.unbroken-dome.test-sets' version '1.4.2'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

testSets {
    integrationTest {
        dirName = 'integration-test'
    }
}

test {
    environment 'MY_ENV_VAR_1', 'my_env_value_1'
}

integrationTest {
    environment 'MY_ENV_VAR_1', 'my_env_value_1000'
}
```

**test method** (in both test and integration-test dirs)

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println(System.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR_1"));
}
```

**runs**

- `gradle test` prints out `my_env_value_1`
- `gradle integrationTest` prints out `my_env_value_1000`
- from IntelliJ: right click on the test and run -> prints nothing. Same for integration test.

I clicked the "Refresh all gradle projects" button in IntelliJ's gradle projects pane. No change.
The question isn't just scoped to environment variable. Ability to load system properties or others from gradle to any run/debug modes in IntelliJ would also be nice.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try this so its a comment rather than an answer but have you tried generating the Intellij projects files through the Gradle idea plugin? Run gradle cleanIdea idea and see what it generates. If that doesn't work then in theory you could manipulate the generating project files from gradle, though it can be a bit of a faff to do so.

Comment: The idea plugin is my gradle file so I suppose the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, be sure that IDE build/run actions are delegated to Gradle instead of handled through IntelliJ natively.  Without this ticked, IntelliJ will attempt to resolve these variables using the properties it is aware of, which may *not* be what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Using the gradle test running or delegating to gradle breaks a few other things though: 1) it's impossible to run individual test methods as gradle doesn't let you do that in the first; 2) IntelliJ run/debug pane for tests loses the test events which cause the pass/fail/crash report for methods to be lost as well. Nice trick, but I seem to be losing more than I'm gaining.

Comment: You *absolutely* can run individual test methods with Gradle.  I do this all the time.  Add some more detail to your question to show us what you're seeing.

Comment: Naw that feature is half broken as it can't run all kinds of junit tests: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cant-rung-single-test-with-tests-which-uses-runwith-parameterized-class/10438 Tests that use \@TestType may also be impacted coz gradle doesn't want to run them for me. I can indeed run individual tests for classes that only use the \@Test, \@Before*, \@After* annotations yeah but that doesn't cover all my use cases so that's still not practical.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ doesn't support this directly. The best you can do is to generate the Intellij project files using the Idea plugin and update the gradle build file to tweak the output.

Environment variables in IntelliJ can be defined as part of the run configuration so you can tweak the gradle build to update the default run configuration for unit tests.

As  prototype, add the following to your build.gradle:

```
idea.workspace.iws.withXml { provider ->
def runManagerNode = provider.asNode().component.find {it.@name == 'RunManager'} as Node
def defaultConfigNode = runManagerNode.configuration.find {it.@default=='true' && it.@type=='JUnit'} as Node

def envsNode = defaultConfigNode.envs[0] as Node
envsNode.appendNode('env', [name: 'MY_ENV_VAR_1', value: test.environment.MY_ENV_VAR_1])
}
```

Now run 'gradlew cleanIdea idea' and open up the resulting project.

Go to run->edit configurations->defaults->junit and you will see that the value of the environment variable has now been passed into IntelliJ.

[image]

This works as far as it goes but has a few problems that would need some thought/work:

1. As the workspace file isn't cleared down, you need to check if the 'env' node already existing before adding it.
2. I've hard coded the 'MY_ENV_VAR_1' name just to show that it works.
3. If you change the values, you will need to re-generate the Idea project files and delete any existing run configurations for JUnit so that they will pick up the new defaults.
4. I haven't thought of a way to distinguish between the test and integrationTest environment variables.